# is there any way to fetch query which has more than 50 lines?

Tags: sql, sql-server, fetch

I have a procedure in SQL Server which has more than 50 lines, but it returns this error if I don't check for returned data:

> Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

I tried to check the query to see if it is correct and it seems to be correct. 
Then I tried another procedure which just has about 5 lines and it gives me correct results.

Is it true that php cannot fetch query with too many lines?

I use it on PHP, is there any possible way to do that, besides changing the query?

Comment: What happens when you run the query on the server directly (rather than through php)?

Comment: sql server?it runs correctly and shows me the data.
thank you

Comment: sry, i mean that the query(procedure) run correctly if i run on the sql server. but when i tried to run using php it showed me nothing.
and if i tried to run the query(straightly query in my procedure) using php it was working correctly.